# Matplotlib & Python: assign a color when doing iterateive plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have `a group of ellipses` to plot, but the ellipses would be plotted in the same color. This makes it hard to differentiate one from another:

```
# import matplotlib as mpl
# from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_ellpises(ell_groups):
    print 'GMM Plot Result'
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for ell in ell_groups:
        xy, width, height, angle = ell
        ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy=xy, width=width, height=height, angle = angle)
        ell.set_alpha(0.5)
        ax.add_patch(ell)
    ax.autoscale()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    return plt.show() 

ell1= [-7.13529086, 5.28809598], 4.42823535, 5.97527801,107.60800706
ell2= [.96850139, 1.33792516], 5.73498868,8.98934084,97.8230716191
ell3= [1.43665497, 3.87692805], 1.42859078, 1.95525638,83.135072216
ell_groups = [ell1,ell2,ell3]
plot_ellpises(ell_groups)
```

[image]

I want to know how can I assign a color to each when plotting, so the ellpises would be easier to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Matplotlib's color-cycle with `ax._get_lines.color_cycle`. This is an iterator, so call `next()` on it each time you draw an ellipse:

```
def plot_ellpises(ell_groups):
    print 'GMM Plot Result'
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    colors = ax._get_lines.color_cycle
    for ell in ell_groups:
        xy, width, height, angle = ell
        ell = mpl.patches.Ellipse(xy=xy, width=width, height=height,
                                  angle = angle, facecolor=next(colors))
        ell.set_alpha(0.5)
        ax.add_patch(ell)
    ax.autoscale()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    return plt.show()
```

[image]

To specify the colors cycled through, you can set them explicitly as rcParams before plotting. e.g., for magenta, red, yellow:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['m', 'r', 'y']
```

[image]

Comment: This is much better than what I've thought. What I did is create a `corlor_set = ['r','g','b']`, and turn the iteration into `for i, ell in enumerate(ell_group).`

Comment: But, how can I change the color style? Mine is quite different from yours.

Comment: There is an additional question, what if I what to plot `4` intead of `3` ellpise? Then I need to add the additional color if I manually specified color set. I'm now thinking `ax._get_lines.color_cycle` may be a better option?